# Round off to 0.5 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in SQL.

How do I round off if:

1.01 -- 1.24 -> 1

1.25 -- 1.49 -> 1.5

1.51 -- 1.74 -> 1.5

1.75 -- 1.99 -> 2

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select floor(val * 2  + 0.5) / 2
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!